# How to do this without eval()

Tags: javascript, variables, eval

```
for (var i in variables) {
    eval('var ' + i + ' = variables[i]');
}
```

Basically, I want to transfer **variables** properties to local variables.

Is there an alternative to using **eval()**

***Or which of these is better:***

**1.**

```
var _ = variables;
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    _.test1();
    _.test2();
    _.test3();
}
```

**2.**

```
with (variables) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        test1();
        test2();
        test3();
    }
}
```

**3.**

```
var test1 = variables.test1,
    test2 = variables.test2,
    test3 = variables.test3;
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    test1();
    test2();
    test3();
}
```

**4.**

```
for (var i in variables) eval('var ' + i + ' = variables[i]');
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    test1();
    test2();
    test3();
}
```

Comment: Why in the world would you like to do this?

Comment: If 'variables' is really long, like: namespace.constructors.blah.dramatic.variables
and the content of variables is referenced a lot, then is useful to have it's content in local variables.

The 'with' keyword could be used but that has it own problems.

the example is simple to keep it simple.

Comment: You should avoid using `eval()` util you know JS well enough to know when it is absolutely necessary to use it because its slow and its use is generally considered bad practice.

Comment: @indie have you read the question title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'll post the answer myself.

**No.**

There is no way to set local variables without knowing the name of the variable without using eval()...

...But using local variables (**option 3**) is the best way.

Answer (score 4):

By looking at your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435492/javascript-how-to-do-this-without-eval/#comment-3578853) seems that your major concern is having to reference several times a deeply nested object, avoiding `eval` and `with` I would simply recommend you to use an alias identifier, for example:

```
 // some local scope...
 var foo = namespace.constructors.blah.dramatic.variables;
 // replace foo with something meaningful :)
 foo.method1();
 foo.method2();
 foo.property1;
 // etc...
```

In that way the deeply nested object will already be resolved and referencing your alias will be faster, `eval` and `with` IMO would only cause you more problems than benefits in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I considered that, of course. But, given that the variables names are known; instead of using an alias I would just repeat what eval does. Like, var a = variables.a; var b = variables.b; and so on... Which I believe is the most efficient method, but not as elegant as I would like. eval saves some bytes but seems like a hack. Setting a dozen variables with eval shouldn't be noticeable performance wise.

Comment: @Carlos Gil Saving "bytes" is a worthless endeavor. If you want to optimize your code to by decreasing scope chain lookup, what @CMS has is the way to go.  Also, `eval` (and sometimes `with`) is slow, and the side effects of an improperly used `with` make it not worth using.

Comment: @Justin Johnson I am quite sure that after initially setting the local variables they are accessed faster than the properties of one of them. Meaning; foo* are accessed faster than foo.property*. If I am terrible wrong, please explain.

Comment: Premature optimization is the .. something.  Using "sav[ing] some bytes" as a reason is thinking in this mindset.

Comment: @strager "saves some bytes" was not a reason, but a statement.

Comment: @Carlos, I would go with your options 1 or 3, check this simple [performance test](http://jsbin.com/uyani3/13/).

Comment: @CMS Nice. In IE8, option 2 is the fastest, seems like the with statement is much more optimized in IE than in Firefox. My script is meant to be run on IE only and in IE7 compatibility mode, but the benchmarking script does not work on IE7. Also, the test should be divided into 2 parts, (a) Setting variables; (b) Accessing variables. (b) is more important because it's much more recurrent, in my script at least. I'll make a test for this. Thanks.

Comment: @Carlos Gil You misunderstand me. I am saying that you should decrease scope chain lookups by creating a local variable.

Comment: @Justin Johnson well, I understood that you endorsed CMS's answer (option 1) which does decrease scope chain lookups, but not as much as option 3 of the original post.

Comment: @Carlos Gil This is a micro optimization, so it really doesn't matter outside of readability, but count along with me: Example #3 has 9 lookups and 3 assignments whereas Example #1 has 6 lookups and 1 assignment.

Comment: @Justin Johnson, I guess it's my fault for not expanding the examples. After the initial assignments, the variables are meant to be looked up thousands of times, as I thought I clarified in the comment with "...and the content of variables is referenced a lot".

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to make the object the current scope. It won't make the properties local variables, but you can access them using the `this` keyword:

```
var variables = { a:42, b:1337 };

(function(){
  alert(this.a);
  alert(this.b);
}).apply(variables);
```

This has the advantage that you are not copying anything anywhere, you are accessing the properties directly.

Comment: How could this possibly be better than just assigning `variables` a shorter name. You'd still be accessing the properties directly.

Comment: @MooGoo: No, if you copy the properties to local variables you will not access the properties directly. If you change the local variable, the property won't change.

Comment: I said "assigning `variables` a shorter name", i.e. `var v = variables`. `v` holds a reference to the same object that `variables` references which is no different than `this` holding that reference, except it is more concise and does not require an unnecessary function call (which is probably as slow if not slower than using `with`).

Comment: @MooGoo: Ok, I see what you mean. No, it's not better, which I never said that it was, it's just another way of doing it.